# Accessing the DB version of the model after a POST

Tags: python, django

I am using the generic UpdateView and I just noticed some undesired behaviour. When I post invalid data get_object is returning the UNSAVED POST version.

How can I access the DB version from my template until it's actually saved?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `form_invalid` method of UpdateView so that it re-fetches the object from the database. Generally the pk will be fetched via the URL conf.

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class NewView(UpdateView):

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        self.object = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.object.pk)
        return super(NewView, self).form_invalid(form)
```